# Sorting each line of numeric data row wise in a text file using python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text file with 3 columns of numeric data, I want to sort each line of the file separately in descending order.

Input File:

```
12 10 5
1 120 3
-1 1 10
-1 -1 -1
```

Output file:

```
12 10 5
120 3 1 
10 1 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

I just tried using the `sorted()` function like this:

```
with codecs.open('BI_TA','r') as f:
    with codecs.open('ta_sort','w') as ff:
        for line in f.readlines():
             line=sorted(line)
             ff.write(line)
```

But this does not work.

Comment: It gives an error like this : <module>
    ff.write(line)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Because `write` doesn't expect a `list`, which is what `sorted` returns. Also, note that you're sorting *characters*, which is not what you want. Look up `str.split` and `str.join`.

Comment: @johnsharpe: Sounds like an *answer* to me...

Comment: @DSM yes,I tried using print before the file write operation, I can see that it is reading the line like a list, instead of reading 120, it reads it as '1','2','0' and so on.. but how do I make it read the whole value in that column?

Comment: You know there's a library for this sort of thing: [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I tried using line=sorted(line.split()) and now it does read the values of each column separately and this is what i get from the print(line) stmt: ['12','10','5']. But the character buffer error is still there.

Comment: Yes, because you need to make it *back into a string*, which is why I also suggested `str.join`. Note that the sort is *lexicographical*, not numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
line=sorted(line)
```

by:

```
line=' '.join(sorted(line.split(), key=int, reverse=True))
```

Say the current line is `1 120 3'. The following actions are applied on this line:

1. `line.split()` -> `['1', '120', '3']`
2. `sorted(['1', '120', '3'], key=int, reverse=True)` -> `['120', '3', '1']` sorts in decending oreder treating each value as `int` because of `key=int`.
3. `line = ' '.join(['120', '3', '1'])` -> `"120 3 1"` converts list to string because `file.write()` accepts only strings.

Comment: Note that this will sort *lexicographically*, which isn't what the OP wants. Also, some explanation of what you've changed and why would be helpful.

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD this works, but can u explain me the logic, I did understand the logic of spliting and joining the string.

Comment: Correct IMO, according to the docs the key argument allows to transform each element of the list into an integer before comparing them, thus it will sort numerically. Didn't know that little trick!

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD I didn't know about the key, thank u for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

list(line).sort() should work.

Comment: No, it really shouldn't; it's no different to `sorted(line)`, except that you can't assign the result (as `sort` is in-place).